# How to subtract two dates with criteria (if data is not existing in another table, use date today, if existing, use the date in there)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables (data2002.dbo.**tblCrew** and eds.dbo.**tblpms**) with tblCrew used as the main table. please note that the primarykey in tblpms are all existing in tblCrew (main). I would like to see if data from tblCrew is existing in tblpms and if it does exists, i need to get the difference of a certain date from tblCrew and another from tblpms.  but if its not existing, i need the difference of dates from tblCrew and the date today.

I am stuck here with my query:

```
SELECT t1.CaseNo, t1.LastName + ', ' + t1.FirstName as fname
, case 
    when (t2.med_stat <> 'Fit To Work' and t2.med_stat <> 'Deceased' 
      and t2.med_stat <> 'Reached Maximum Medical Cure' 
      and t2.med_stat <> 'Stop Treatment') 
          then datediff(day,cast(t1.DatePIConsult as datetime), getdate()) 
    else
      datediff(day,cast(t1.DatePIConsult as datetime),cast(t2.med_stateff as datetime))        end as
TreatmentDays 

from data2002.dbo.tblCrew as t1
 join eds.dbo.tblpms as t2 
   on t1.CaseNo COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = t2.CaseNo COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

which brings me this result (which isnt what i expected):

```
CaseNo          Name                    Days
AM06-009-CRW    VILLARINO, RICHARD  
BLB13-014-CRW   ARQUISOLA, REDEN    
JPI12-028-CRW   OBENQUE, JOSE   
JPI12-037-CRW   TARRO, ANGELO   
JPI12-039-CRW   DELA CRUZ, FELICIANO    121
NOE12-205-CRW   CLAVIO, RAYMUND 
NOE12-205-CRW   CLAVIO, RAYMUND
```

i was hoping more like this one (sample):

```
CaseNo          Name                    Days
BM07-029-CRW    ASASPOK, RICH           119
CLC14-014-CRW   QDASF, READS            115
```

what I would like (hoping @_@) to achieve, is specified below):

a. if there are 20 lines existing in table1 and 10 lines from table2. can I have the result in 20 lines (based on table1) and not from the table2 (because table1 always have more data than table2).

b. i would also like to add in my query to show only distinct CaseNo and if 3rd column is not null.

c. another criterion is only where the value in 3rd column is between 109 and 121 (real val = 110-120).

hope you could help me with this one.. thanks so much in advance

Comment: Are there some columns where `t1.DatePIConsult` from Main table is empty? Also try `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`.

Comment: yes thats right.. though it shouldn't be but the users kept on doing so.. =P.. so i have to consider that..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the max date (per primarykey) and get its difference with the one from another table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241745/how-can-i-get-the-max-date-per-primarykey-and-get-its-difference-with-the-one)

Comment: no its not, though its also my post.. this is a different scenario.. thanks.. it just so happen that the difference of two dates is still included..

Comment: @E-rGabrielDoronila : Did you try `Left join` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT t1.CaseNo, t1.LastName + ', ' + t1.FirstName as fname
, case 
    when t2.CaseNo IS NULL 
        THEN datediff(day,cast(t1.DatePIConsult as datetime), getdate()) 
    when t2.med_stat NOT IN ('Fit To Work',
                             'Deceased',
                             'Reached Maximum Medical Cure',
                             'Stop Treatment') 
          then datediff(day,cast(t1.DatePIConsult as datetime), getdate()) 
    else
      datediff(day,cast(t1.DatePIConsult as datetime),cast(t2.med_stateff as datetime))

  end as TreatmentDays 
from data2002.dbo.tblCrew as t1
left join eds.dbo.tblpms as t2 
on t1.CaseNo COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = t2.CaseNo COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```