# How can I get the max date (per primarykey) and get its difference with the one from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this sample data below (table1):

```
PKEY   DATE
----   ----
ABC1   2/13
CFG5   1/05
POK9   1/10
```

and I have these dates from another table (table2):

```
PKEY   REF#   DATE
----   ----   ----
1      ABC1   2/14
2      ABC1   2/20
3      ABC1   3/01
4      CFG5   3/05
5      CFG5   2/10
6      ABC1   2/25
```

I want to get the **max** date from **table2** (**per REF#**) and get the **difference** with the date from **table1**. showing the below result.

```
REF#   DIFF   
----   ----
POK9    55
CFG5    54
ABC1    21  [ *note: this is equal to datediff(day,table1.DATE,getdate()) ]
```

*ALSO, i want to use the date **today** (to be deducted with the date from table1) if REF# is not existing in table2 (like the 3rd row in the above example).  Hope this makes sense.. let me know if there's anything unclear so I can edit right away..

**UPDATE:
this is what i've tried so far.. but still incomplete.. thanks for the hardwork

```
select t1.[REF#]
from table1 as t1
join table2 as t2
on t1.[REF#] COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = t2.[REF#] COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.PKEY, CASE WHEN o.DATE IS NULL 
                     THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.DATE, GETDATE()) 
                     ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.DATE, o.DATE) END AS DIFF
FROM dbo.table1 t1 OUTER APPLY (
                                SELECT MAX(t2.Date) AS Date
                                FROM dbo.table2 t2     
                                WHERE t1.PKEY = t2.REF# 
                                ) o
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d6913/1)

OR without APPLY() operator

```
SELECT t1.PKEY, (SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(o.Date) IS NULL 
                             THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.Date, GETDATE()) 
                             ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.Date, MAX(o.Date)) END AS DIFF
                 FROM dbo.test27 o
                 WHERE t1.PKEY = o.REF#
                 ) AS DIFF                               
FROM dbo.test26 t1
```

query with your criteria

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT t1.PKEY, (SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(o.Date) IS NULL 
                              THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.Date, GETDATE()) 
                              ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.Date, MAX(o.Date)) END AS DIFF
                       FROM dbo.test27 o
                       WHERE t1.PKEY = o.REF#
                       ) AS DIFF                               
      FROM dbo.test26 t1
      ) s
WHERE s.DIFF BETWEEN 110 AND 120
```

Comment: I get the error, "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OUTER'. Error Code 156"

Comment: i don't really know where i got it wrong.. i tried to compare it with the demo in SQLFiddle.. but my code doesnt seem to work.. this is my code

---
SELECT t1.CaseNo, CASE WHEN o.med_stateff IS NULL 
                     THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.DatePIConsult, GETDATE()) 
                     ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.DatePIConsult, o.med_stateff) END AS DIFF
FROM data2002.dbo.tblCrew t1 OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT MAX(t2.med_stateff) AS Date
                                FROM eds.dbo.tblpms t2     
                                WHERE t1.CaseNo = t2.CaseNo 
                                ) o

Comment: i'm not sure.. bt maybe i get the error because my two tables were from different databases.. T.T.. how can I make this work?.. this is my updated code

---- SELECT t1.CaseNo, CASE WHEN o.Date IS NULL 
                     THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.DatePIConsult, GETDATE()) 
                     ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.DatePIConsult, o.Date) END AS DIFF
FROM data2002.dbo.tblCrew t1 OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT MAX(t2.med_stateff) AS Date
                                FROM eds.dbo.tblpms t2     
                                WHERE t1.CaseNo = t2.CaseNo 
                                ) o

Comment: To use APPLY, the database compatibility level must be at least 90.

Comment: hi.. this code works.. but may i also know how to add a criteria to show only the lines that diff is between 110 and 120? -- below is my 'WHERE' code but it doesn't work (error at 'BETWEEN' line).. i put it in the where clause

where t1.date is not null and
(SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(o.date) IS NULL 
                             THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.Date, GETDATE()) 
                             ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.Date, MAX(o.date)) END between 110 and 120

Comment: hi Alexander.. can you also add the criteria to show only those lines that 'DIFF' is between 110 and 120, please? im sure im not doing it correctly because i dont really know where to put the lines? -- ie DIFF between 110 and 120.. thanks

Comment: ok i got it.. thanks again alexander.. i just rearranged my codes, yours worked fine.. thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH recorddates
AS
(
    SELECT  PKEY, REFNo, DATE,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RefNO
                                ORDER BY DATE DESC) rn
    FROM    table2
)
SELECT  a.PKEY, 
        datediff(day,a.DATE,b.date) 
FROM    table1 a
        INNER JOIN recorddates b
            ON a.PKey = b.RefNo
WHERE   b.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
select a.pkey
      ,datediff(day, max(a.date), coalesce(max(b.date), getdate())) as diff 
  from table1      a
  left join table2 b on(b.ref# = a.pkey)
 group 
    by a.pkey;
```

Edited for comments:
You should be able to filter like this:

```
select a.pkey
      ,datediff(day, max(a.date), coalesce(max(b.date), getdate())) as diff 
  from table1      a
  left join table2 b on(b.ref# = a.pkey)
 group 
    by a.pkey
having datediff(day, max(a.date), coalesce(max(b.date), getdate())) between 110 
                                                                        and 120;
```

or by wrapping the statment like this:

```
select *
  from (select a.pkey
              ,datediff(day, max(a.date), coalesce(max(b.date), getdate())) as diff 
          from table1      a
          left join table2 b on(b.ref# = a.pkey)
         group 
            by a.pkey
       )
 where diff between 110 and 120;
```

Comment: GREAT! but... i need to filter out (not include) some lines with null a.date.. this query still has lines that is null in the 'diff' column.. thanks Ronnis in advance

Comment: ok i got it.. but where can I put this "WHERE diff between 110 and 120"? I am getting error when I copy the whole aggregate function in the where clause.. it says "An aggregate
may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery
contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the
column being aggregated is an outer reference."

Comment: @E-rGabrielDoronila, you can put the expression in the having clause or wrapping it in another statement. I updated the answer with examples.